# Huge gap on page between content and footer

Tags: css, html

I'm having a problem with a huge gap in between the content and the footer ad. I can't quite figure out how to fix it. I suspect it may be to do with the content on the right as it is generated by another site (indeed.com).

Here's the link:

http://www.immediatestarts.co.uk/

Much appreciated if anyone can help.

Comment: Some JS code is setting the height of your `<iframe>` to `2000px`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually the Javascript file you are embedding within  that is writing an iframe out to the screen with a height of 2000px. I'm guessing you don't have control over that since it's coming from a third-party site, so you could try writing a CSS rule on your page to control the iframe, such as

```
#indeedjobs iframe {
 height: 1000px;
}
```

**Edit:** Alternatively if that isn't working, you could just set the height of `#indeedjobs` itself to `height:1000px`, then set `overflow:hidden` on the div as well if you want to prevent the iframe from spilling outside of it.

Comment: Thanks. "#indeedjobs iframe {height: 1000px;}" didn't work, but setting the height of the div and the hiding the overflow makes it look fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You're putting a height of 2000px onto the iframe, in an inline style (ie `<iframe style="height: 2000px">` - remove that, and it'll be fine.